# Inserting relationship with linking table

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have some problems regarding inserting a new record with the relationships model. I have 3 tables `Contacts`, `Contact_Customer` and `Customers`. The models are as followed:

Contact.php

```
class Contact extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'FIRST_NAME',
        'INSERTION',
        'LAST_NAME',
        'EMAIL',
        'PHONE_NUMBER',
    ];

   public function contact_customers(){
        return $this->HasMany(Contact_Customer::class, 'CONTACT_ID','ID');
    }
}
```

Contact_Customer.php

```
class Contact_Customer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'CONTACT_ID',
        'CUSTOMER_ID'
    ];

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'ID');
    }

    public function contact(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Contact::class, 'ID');
    }
}
```

Customer.php

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'COMPANY_NAME',
        'ZIPCODE',
        'STREET',
        'HOUSE_NUMBER',
        'CITY',
        'COUNTRY',
    ];

    public function contact_customers(){
        return $this->HasMany(Contact_Customer::class, 'CUSTOMER_ID','ID');
    }

}
```

I have wrote a function in the `ContactController` to add a contact to a customer with this function:

```
public function create(Request $request, $customer_id)
    {
        $contact = Contact::create([
            'FIRST_NAME' => $request->input('first_name'),
            'INSERTION' => $request->input('insertion'),
            'LAST_NAME' => $request->input('last_name'),
            'EMAIL' => $request->input('email'),
            'PHONE_NUMBER' => $request->input('phone'),
        ]);

        $contact_customer = Contact_Customer::create([
            'CUSTOMER_ID' => $customer_id,
            'CONTACT_ID' => $contact->id
        ]);

        $customer = Customer::find($customer_id);
        $customer->push();

        return redirect('/customer/'.$customer_id.'/show');
    }
```

The records will be pushed to the database but the view gives me this error: Trying to get property 'FIRST_NAME' of non-object (View: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/resources/views/customer/show.blade.php)

And my view is like this

```
<h2>Contactpersonen</h2>
        <table class="table table-borderless">
            <tbody>
            @foreach($customer->contact_customers as $contact)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $contact->contact->FIRST_NAME }} {{$contact->contact->INSERTION}} {{$contact->contact->LAST_NAME }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $contact->contact->PHONE_NUMBER }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $contact->contact->EMAIL }}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <h2>Aanmaken contactpersoon</h2>
        <form method="POST" action="/customer/{{$customer->ID}}/contact/create" id="contactform">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="customer">Voornaam</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="zipcode">Tussenvoegsel</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="insertion" name="insertion">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="street">Achternaam</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="house_number">E-mail</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="country">Mobiel</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Toevoegen</button>
        </form>
```

So the view does not see the new relationship. I have tried to multiple sollutions on slack and read the laracast https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models. But I can not find a solution.

Hopefully you see my mistake, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below given code in App\Contact_Customer.php may be your relation are not linked correctly

```
class Contact_Customer extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'CONTACT_ID',
    'CUSTOMER_ID'
];

 public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'CUSTOMER_ID', 'ID');
}

public function contact(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Contact::class, 'CONTACT_ID', 'ID');
}
}
```

Comment: Should be nothing wrong with the relationship. When I add the rows to the database itself the page works. But when I use laravel to create new records I get the error message.

Comment: because your relation is getting `null` due to default functionality of eloquent orm which is if you don't declare 3rd parameter so laravel eloquent assume that the foreign key name will be `contact_id` but in your case its `CONTACT_ID`

Comment: I have swapped 'ID' and 'CUSTOMER_ID', which worked. Thanks!